# Hide Android Toolbar when scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, android-toolbar

I want to hide my Toolbar if I scroll down in my ListView in a ListFragment (which implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener) and show it again if I scroll upwards. I use this code but there it shows a flickering toolbar:

```
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {   }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (view.getId() == listView.getId()) {
                final int currentFirstVisibleItem = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                    // getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
                } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                    // getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
                    ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
                }

                mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
            }
        }
    });
```

***EDIT***
I found a problem because I already have used the OnScrollListener to detect if the end of the ListView is reached. But how can I avoid the conflict?

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    // Leave this empty
}

/**
 * Method to detect if scrolled to end of listview
 *
 * @param listView
 * @param scrollState
 */
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView listView, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        int threshold = 0;
        if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= listView.getCount() - 1 - threshold) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Scrolled to end of list, load more articles");
            currentPage++;
            Log.d(TAG, "CurrentPage for EndlessAdapter:" + currentPage);
            // Load more articles
            loadMoreArticles(currentPage);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone an idea or improvement proposals?

Comment: Why not do everything in a single scroll listener instead of different ones?

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem, I am such an idiot ;-) I put all the code in my onScrollStateChanged method.